# Removing period from number in python

Tags: python

Given a real number between 0 and 1 (for example 0.2836) I want to return only the number without the dot (for example in this case from 0.2836 -> 2836 or 02836). I was trying to use python to do this but I just started and I need some help.

Comment: Show what you have tried. (and you mean *period*, not comma)

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I don't know where to begin

Comment: `str(number).replace('.','')`

Comment: `number = number.translate(None, '.').lstrip('0')`

Comment: *What have you tried* to read on the Python documentation, then?

Comment: I'd also done 'int(str(number).replace('.', ''))' but I searched for other ways and I found this function of the _math_ module that may interests you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681743/splitting-a-number-into-the-integer-and-decimal-parts-in-python

Answer (score 5):

As long as you have a number, the following should do:

```
>>> number = 0.2836
>>> int(str(number).replace('.', ''))
2836
```

If a `.` is not found in the string, [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) just returns the original string.

With more numbers:

```
>>> int(str(1).replace('.', ''))
1
>>> int(str(1.2).replace('.', ''))
12
```

Comment: As far as I can see the command works with numbers with less than 12 digits after the comma, is there a way to have more digits returned?

Comment: @Peterix [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#floating-point-arithmetic-issues-and-limitations)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to remove an unwanted character from a strip is to call its `.replace` method with an empty string as the second argument:

```
x = str(123.45)
x = x.replace('.','')
print(x)                 # Prints 12345
```

Note, this would leave any leading zeros (i.e. `0.123` using this method would result in `0123`)

If you know there are always, say, 4 numbers after the decimal (and in the case that there are less, you want trailing zeros), you could multiply the number by an appropriate factor first:

```
x = 123.4567
x *= 10000
x = str(int(x))          # Convert float to integer first, then to string
print(x)                 # Prints 1234567
```

There are other options, but this may point you in the right direction.