# How to iterate a float in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, floating-point

So now I have a variable which is x = 1001.0010101

From this x, I wanna separate into two parts:

```
x = 1001.0010101
val_int = int(x)                         #get val_int   = 1001
val_fract = {0:.5f}".format(a - val_int) #get val_fract = 0.00101
```

Is it possible to use for loop to iterate the val_fract to be like: (ignore the int part and decimal point)

```
0 
0 
1 
0 
1
```

I have tried so many times and I couldn't get it done and the system told me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 46, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to convert the variable into a string object and then use regular expressions to get what you want.

Comment: I just tried using a split method to separate two parts. However, the decimal part has not been fully split, what I meant is the second part would only take 10101 and **00**(these two zeros)10101 are missing.

Comment: What is your code for the split appraoch, can you append it to your question?

Comment: Can you explain more what this is for? It's an odd thing to be doing, and I suspect there's a better way to solve whatever the underlying problem is. Note that the value `1001.0010101` *can't be represented* in a Python `float`. The best you can get is `1001.001010100000030433875508606433868408203125` instead. Do you want to see all those digits in the fractional part? If not, what's your criterion for truncating them?

Comment: Actually I'm doing a binary converter, so that's why the digits are in 1 and 0, so I don't need any other numbers, so I could just limit the length of the decimal part.

Comment: Then you definitely shouldn't be storing `1001.0010101` in a Python `float`. You should be representing it as a string, not a number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `math` module in python to separate decimal and integer part

```
import math 
x = 1001.0010101
math.modf(x)
#output:(0.0010101000000304339, 1001.0)
```

Iterate as you want

Have doubt about extra numbers in end of decimal read [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)

Comment: This answer has not fulfilled my wish! Haha, it's ok I got something new! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, why you suggest in your comment that leading zeros are missing:

```
x = 1001.0010101
#separate fractional from integer part
frac = str(x).split(".")

for digit in frac[1]:
    print(digit)
```

Alternatively, you can transform both parts into lists of integers:

```
#integer digits
x_int = list(map(int, frac[0]))
#fractional digits
x_frac = list(map(int, frac[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks man! Works fine! Because I was just like converting the decimal part using 
`num = 123.456
split_num = str(num).split('.')
int_part = int(split_num[0])
decimal_part = int(split_num[1])`
Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681743/splitting-a-number-into-the-integer-and-decimal-parts-in-python
It just has its disadvantages using this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 1001.0010101
x = "{0:.5f}".format(x)
for i in str(x).split(".")[1]:
    print(i)
```

**Output**:

```
0
0
1
0
1
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept ans if it solved your problem. Thanks