# Convert float to float time in python

Tags: python, odoo

How in python code convert 10.5 to 10:30 (10 hours and 30 minutes).

Now **time = 10.5**   I need result **time = 10:30**

Any simple solution?

Tnx all for help

Comment: where is your code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

time = 10.5

```
print '{0:02.0f}:{1:02.0f}'.format(*divmod(float(time) * 60, 60))
```

> > > 10:30

Comment: Could you add a bit of explanation? And maybe a link to the `divmod` docs?

Answer (score 2):

Split the number into its integer and decimal parts, then multiply the decimal part with 60 and put them back together:

```
t = 10.5

hour, minute = divmod(t, 1)
minute *= 60
result = '{}:{}'.format(int(hour), int(minute))
# result: 10:30
```

See also the documentation for the [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) function and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681743/splitting-a-number-into-the-integer-and-decimal-parts) for other ways to split a float into two parts.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the raw float value as `hours` to `datetime.timedelta()`, and then operate with it in what I think is the most comfortable way:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

td = timedelta(hours=10.5)
dt = datetime.min + td
print("{:%H:%M}".format(dt))
print(td.total_seconds())
```