# Efficiently convert Decimal to whole and fractional as integers

Tags: python

What is the best way to convert Decimal to a pair of integers to get whole and fractional in python?
By saying best - I mean efficient, exact and using underlaying structure of the data type.
e.g.:

```
d = Decimal('1536310893.687185000')
whole, fractional = some_func(d)
print(whole)
1536310893
print(fractional)
687185000
```

I believe there is more efficient way than to just split string representation :)
I also think that Decimal is stored in memory as a pair of integers, the question is how to get them? :)

Comment: Ah..., can you please explain a little more?

Comment: Let's start with one of the requirements - exact. What is the exact _fractional_ (you mean decimal?) value of `4/3` as an integer?

Comment: So if I enter `0.25` then you want to get the fraction `1/4` ?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681743/splitting-a-number-into-the-integer-and-decimal-parts]

Comment: it is not what I want

Comment: Do you want 123.45 and 123.045 to give the same result for the fractional part? If not, what results do you want in those cases?

Comment: Mark, good point, I did not think through it. Thanks. Then I need the same result + a number of digits after a point...

Answer (score 2):

Use [divmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod)

```
>>> divmod(d, 1)
(Decimal('1536310893'), Decimal('0.687185000'))
```

Comment: I need them as integers

Comment: Add support for integers

Comment: at least looks promising. I need to know the number of digits after fixed point, and then I can make them integers

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `split`:

```
d = Decimal('1536310893.687185000')
whole, fractional = map(float,str(d).split('.'))
print(whole)
print(fractional)
```

Output:

```
1536310893
687185000
```

Better `math.modf`:

```
import math
whole, fractional = math.modf(d)
```

Comment: yeah cool, it is not efficient to convert to string :( I think decimal is stored in memory as two integers...

Comment: modf uses floats as output - it is not exact. I also think, Decimal is stored in memory as a pair of integers, the question is how to get them?

Comment: @ЕвгенийАртеменко Well than, i don't know how, but first solution works but inefficient tho

Answer (score 1):

If you need it done by using the properties of the Decimal class you can use this function for `some_func()`:

```
from decimal import *

def whole_and_fractional_part(d):
    getcontext().rounding = ROUND_FLOOR
    return d.to_integral_exact(), d - d.to_integral_exact()
```

This gives the output:

```
In [34]: whole, fractional
Out[34]: (Decimal('1536310893'), Decimal('0.687185'))
```

Comment: looks promising, I just need to know a number of digits after fixed point (x), and then I can multiply Fractional part by 10^x. I think It could be the most efficient. I ned to measure perforamnce...

Answer (score 1):

Decimal can be created with tuple (sign, digits, exponent) where a sign (0 for positive or 1 for negative), a tuple of digits, and an integer exponent. decimal.as_tuple() return this representation. using those options we can write the following:

```
def whole_frac_int(d):
    sign,digits,exp = d.normalize().as_tuple()
    return ( 
      int( decimal.Decimal( (sign,digits[:exp],0) ) ),
      int( decimal.Decimal( (sign,digits[exp:],0) ) )
    )
```

---

```
>>> whole_frac_int( decimal.Decimal('1536310893.687185000')
(1536310893, 687185)
```